# $|g(x)| \ge |f(x)| \implies |\int^1_0g(x)| \ge |\int^1_0f(x)|$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $g,f$ be integrable functions in the interval $[0,1]$

I know that $g(x) \ge f(x) \implies \int^1_0g(x) \ge \int^1_0f(x)$

Is the following truth as well?:

$|g(x)| \ge |f(x)| \implies |\int^1_0g(x)| \ge |\int^1_0f(x)|$?

Comment: If that were true in general, since $|f(x)| \ge||f(x)||$ you would get $\left|\int_0^1 f\right| \ge \left| \int_0^1 |f| \right| = \int_0^1 |f| $. But we also have $\left|\int_0^1 f\right| \le \int_0^1 |f|$, so $$\left|\int_0^1 f\right| = \int_0^1 |f|$$

Answer (score 2):

No. To construct a counter-example, consider $f(x) = 1$ (the constant function $1$), and define $g(x) = 2$ for $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2}$ and $g(x) = -2$ for $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1$. Then clearly $\lvert g(x) \rvert > \lvert f(x) \rvert$, but
$$ \left \lvert \int_0^1 g(x) dx \right \rvert = 0$$
and
$$ \left \lvert \int_0^1 f(x) dx \right \rvert = 1$$.